# How to make logical inference from simulated data

Tags: machine-learning, simulation, classification

I have data collected from a computer simulation of football games which seem to have 
recurring patterns of the following form.

*if madrid plays arsernal and the match ends under 3 goal, then on their next match against each others,
madrid will win. if madrid happens to loose and then plays against chelsea next, they will win 90% of the time.*

how do I find such inferences from simulation generated data like this. There are other forms of hidden patterns that I believe exists in the dataset.

Comment: It seems irrelevant to the question that the data is simulated: it could just as well come from a database of real football games. (Also, your simulation seems to be rather unrealistic. Why would Madrid, a Spanish team, be playing consecutive games against Arsenal and Chelsea, two British teams? The only competition they'd meet in would be the UEFA Champions' League and a club rarely, if ever, plays two consecutive Champions' League games without a domestic league game between them.)